# SQL to allocate rows from one table to another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to allocate rows from one table to another using a sort on TopLvlOrd field. The inputs are the [Orders] table and the [Defects] table. I would like to create an SQL that produces [Output]. Even after a bunch of online research I'm not sure how to do this. I'd prefer not to do a cursor, but will go there if necessary. Any ideas? Using SQL Server 2012.

Rules:
(1) Allocate by TopLvlOrd asc,
(2) Allocate one TopLvlOrd row per PegQty

[Orders]

```
TopLvlOrd  IntOrd  PegQty
=========  ======  ======
67         25      3
120        25      1
111        25      1
16         25      1
127        25      1
127        65      1
127        85      1
```

[Defects]

```
DefectID  IntOrd  TotQty
========  ======  ======
1         25      10
2         25      10
3         25      10
4         25      10
5         25      10
6         25      10
7         25      10
8         25      10
9         25      10
10        25      10
11        65      1
12        85      2
13        85      2
```

[Output]

```
DefectID  IntOrd  TotQty  TopLvlOrd
========  ======  ======  =========
1         25      10      16
2         25      10      67
3         25      10      67
4         25      10      67
5         25      10      111
6         25      10      120
7         25      10      127
8         25      10      NULL
9         25      10      NULL
10        25      10      NULL
11        65      1       127
12        85      2       127
13        85      2       NULL
```

Comment: Please explain the rules you are using.

Comment: I realized I left out the PegQty field part of this problem. I have added that and also added the rules I am trying to implement.

Comment: Yes, I think I need to explode out [Orders] so PegQty is always 1. For example, explode TopLvlOrd 67 into 3 rows with PegQty .= 1. Maybe use a CTE such as in this article: https://alessandroalpi.blog/2013/07/04/repeating-rows-based-on-a-value-in-a-different-column/

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, I'm not sure how I would combine the CTE with the code suggestions made into one SQL statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please  another time make another question. Please check this query:

```
  SELECT  DefectID, IntOrd,
  TotQty, TopLvlOrd, PegQty
  FROM
    (
     SELECT B. DefectID, COALESCE (A.IntOrd, B. IntOrd) IntOrd,
     B.TotQty, A. TopLvlOrd, A.PegQty FROM
    
     (
      SELECT TopLvlOrd ,IntOrd, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION By IntOrd  ORDER by   
      TopLvlOrd) Num, PegQty FROM Orders
     ) A
    
     FULL JOIN
    
    (
      SELECT DefectID , IntOrd ,TotQty, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION By IntOrd  ORDER by   
      TotQty) Num FROM Orders
    ) B

      ON A. IntOrd=B.IntOrd AND A.Num=B.Num
    
   )C
    
    JOIN
    master.dbo.spt_values Tab
    ON Tab.type='P' AND Tab.number<C.PegQty
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. This works for my situation with slight modifications. I have learned a lot. I will avoid modifying posts in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This answers the original version of the question.

I think you want to join on an implicit sequence number, which you can add using `row_number()`:

```
select d.*, o.*
from (select d.*,
             row_number() over (partition by intord order by defectid) as seqnum
      from defects d
     ) d left join
     (select o.*,
             row_number() over (partition by IntOrd order by TopLvlOrd) as seqnum
      from orders o
     ) o
     on d.intord = o.intord and d.seqnum = o.seqnum
```

Comment: Brilliant. I didn't know you could do that. I modified the problem slightly, but I think this answered the original problem. Not sure how to extend this answer to the new rules?

Comment: Will do. I'm new to this forum, so still learning proper etiquette.

Comment: @user3093820 . . . I'm curious why you unaccepted this answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT B. DefectID, COALESCE (A.IntOrd, B. IntOrd) IntOrd,
 B.TotQty, A. TopLvlOrd FROM

(
SELECT    TopLvlOrd ,IntOrd , ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION By IntOrd  ORDER by TopLvlOrd) Num FROM Orders
) A

 FULL JOIN

(
 SELECT DefectID , IntOrd ,TotQty, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION By IntOrd  ORDER by TotQty) Num FROM Orders
) B
ON A. IntOrd=B.IntOrd AND A. Num=B.Num
```

Comment: Brilliant. I didn't know you could do that. I modified the problem slightly, but I think this answered the original problem. Not sure how to extend this answer to the new rules?

Comment: [Output] changed so that TopLvlOrd repeats by PegQty. 67 is repeated 3x in the output.